# Setting custom paper size with QPrinter doesn't print correctly

Tags: qt, printing, qprinter

I need to be able to print from qt (the rendered contents of a `QGraphicsScene`, or a `QImage`), to scale, on normal printer, pdf, but also on **custom** printers, including roll fed.

It seems that anything that works for standard printers fails on custom printers, and the reverse.

I have made the printing work as expected on custom printers now (going back and forth between what works in the different printers).

- I set the custom size required, and the preferred orientation, based on length/width ratio.
- I open a print dialog (and even check the supply- the paper is set to desired size, and the orientation is set as expected)
- print:
  On custom printer, I get the correct size, and if the supply is smaller, the print clips as needed. margins are set correctly too.
  On Pdf, I get a document of custom size as requested, printed correctly - but the orientation is not respected !!! (even though print dialog showed it correctly) - see image
  On HP printer, I get a white page - nothing gets printed.

[image]

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QPrintDialog>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // some scene to print - show rectangle for easy measure
    QGraphicsScene* s = new QGraphicsScene();
    s->setSceneRect(-500, -500, 1500, 1500);
    s->setBackgroundBrush(Qt::red);
    QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView();
    view->setScene(s);
    view->show();
    qreal in = 72;
    QRectF canvasRect(-0.1*in, -0.1*in, 6*in, 4*in);
    qreal margins = 0.1*in;
    QRectF actualCanvasRect = canvasRect.adjusted(margins,margins,-margins,-margins);
    // this is to show actual scene
    QGraphicsRectItem* contourItem = new QGraphicsRectItem(actualCanvasRect);
    contourItem->setBrush(Qt::blue);
    s->addItem(contourItem);
    // an item partially on canvas (so I can check margins)
    QGraphicsRectItem* item = new QGraphicsRectItem(-.5*in, -in, 2*in, 3*in);
    item->setBrush(Qt::yellow);
    s->addItem(item);

    // actual printing:

    // print the scene, to scale, using user margins, on given printer
    QPrinter printer;
    QPrinter::Orientation orient = (actualCanvasRect.width() >
                                    actualCanvasRect.height() ?
                                    QPrinter::Landscape : QPrinter::Portrait);
    printer.setOrientation(orient);
    printer.setPaperSize(canvasRect.size(), QPrinter::Point);
    printer.setPageMargins(margins, margins, margins, margins, QPrinter::Point);

    QPrintDialog printDialog(&printer);
    if (printDialog.exec() != QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        qDebug("dialog canceled");
        return 1;
    }

    QPainter painter;
    if (! painter.begin(&printer))
    {
        qDebug("failed to open printer");
        return 1;
    }

    // render the contents, clipped to printer page size, and scaled from point to device pixel

    QRectF source = actualCanvasRect;

    // convert target rect to DevicePixel and clip to page
    QRectF page = printer.pageRect(QPrinter::DevicePixel);
    qreal scale = printer.resolution()/in;
    QRectF target = QRectF(page.topLeft(), source.size() * scale);
    target &= page; // clip target rect to page

    // clip source rect to page - without this, if printer paper is smaller I get unwanted scaling
    source &= printer.pageRect(QPrinter::Point);

    s->render(&painter, target, source);
    painter.end();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I don't understand why pdf creates a portrait page even though I clearly requested landscape (without changing the print dialog: see image). (the width and height are reversed, yet correct - Document Properties shows 4x6, and the page attempts to print correctly and to scale)

[image]

More important, I don't understand why a typical laser jet printer prints nothing - blank page - or sometimes for a simple canvas it scales to fit.
BUT if I change any properties in the print dialog from HP, anything irrelevant (like paper source, or paper type.... ), it prints correctly.

What am I doing wrong ?

(using Qt 4.7 and 5.5, must work on 4.7 - Windows, have yet to try Linux)

Comment: Guessing here, maybe you could try to move the `painter.begin()` to just before `s->render(...)`? If the paint engine stores some data at `begin()` which gets only updated if changing the properties in the print dialog?

Comment: The `painter.begin()` is after the dialog is completed - the only thing between it and the render is the calculations of source and destination for rendering. And the rendering is performed correctly - the printer page setup isn't. Moving it made no difference.

Comment: Seems that is how it is supposed to act. Here from the documentation:

void QPrinter::setPaperSize(const QSizeF &paperSize, Unit unit)
Sets the paper size based on paperSize in unit.

Note that the paper size is defined in a portrait layout, regardless of what the current printer orientation is set to.